# Modulus and argument of complex number $(1+ie^{i\theta})^n$

Tags: calculus, complex-numbers

Find the modulus and an argument of $(1+ie^{i\theta})^n$, where $\theta \in [0,2\pi[$

I find $\left |  (1+ie^{i\theta})^n \right | = (2(1-\sin\theta))^{\frac{n}{2}}$.
But I don't know what to do to calculate the argument...
Thanks for your help !

Comment: $\arg(z^n) = n \arg z$.

Comment: thanks. But I don't know how to calculate the argument of  1+ieiθ ;

Comment: @MattPoldy multiplying by $i$ rotates the unit circle by $90$ degrees and adding $1$ moves its center from $(0,0)$ to $(1,0)$. You can easily draw a picture of that.

Answer (score 1):

> Find the modulus and an argument of $(1+ie^{i\theta})^n$, where $\theta \in [0,2\pi)$

I am assuming that $~n \in \Bbb{Z_{\neq 0}}.$

First of all, it is understood that all **non-zero** complex numbers can be converted into polar coordinates $~re^{i\alpha},~$ where $~r \in \Bbb{R^+},~$ and $0 \leq \alpha < 2\pi.$

It is also understood that no such polar coordinates exists for the complex number $~0,~$ since you can not meaningfully associate a unique angle $~\alpha,~$ with the complex number $~0.$

$e^{i\theta} = \cos(\theta) + i\sin(\theta).$

Therefore, $~i \times e^{i\theta} = -\sin(\theta) + i\cos(\theta).$

Therefore, $~1 + ie^{i\theta}~$ equals $~x + iy,~$ where:

- $x = 1 - \sin(\theta).~$
- $y = \cos(\theta).$

Therefore,

$$\left[1 + ie^{i\theta}\right]^n = (x + iy)^n,$$

where $~x,y~$ are defined as bullet pointed above.

The first thing to do is to determine under what circumstances you would have $~(x + iy)^n = 0.~$  This will be true if and only if $~\sin(\theta) = 1.~$  Therefore, it will be assumed, without loss of generality, that $~\sin(\theta) \neq 1.~$

---

At this point, the easiest thing to do is take advantage of [De Moivre's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Moivre%27s_formula).  So, simply convert $~(x + iy)~$ into the polar coordinates $~re^{i\alpha}.~$

Then, you will have that $~\left[re^{i\alpha}\right]^n = r^n \times e^{in\alpha},$ which will imply that the modulus is $~r^n,~$ and the argument is $~n\alpha.$

---

So, the first step is to convert $~x + iy~$ into polar coordinates, of the form $~r[\cos(\alpha) + i\sin(\alpha)],~$ where $~r \in \Bbb{R^+},~$ and $0 \leq \alpha < 2\pi.~$

First of all,

$$r = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2} = \sqrt{\left[1 - \sin(\theta)\right]^2 + \cos^2(\theta)} 
\\
=\sqrt{1 - 2\sin(\theta) + \sin^2(\theta) + \cos^2(\theta)} 
\\
= \sqrt{2 - 2\sin(\theta)}. \tag1 $$

Once $~r~$ is found, then $x + iy~$ may be re-expressed as

$$r \times \left[\frac{x}{r} + i\frac{y}{r}\right]. \tag2 $$

The point of the re-expression in (2) above is that

$$\left[\frac{x}{r}\right]^2 + \left[\frac{y}{r}\right]^2 = 1.$$

This implies that there exists a unique angle $~\alpha~$ such that $~0 \leq \alpha < 2\pi,~$ and $~\cos(\alpha) = \dfrac{x}{r}, ~\sin(\alpha) = \dfrac{y}{r}.~$

Therefore, this unique angle $~\alpha,~$ may be construed to be the argument of

$$[x + iy] = r \times \left[ ~\dfrac{x}{r} + i\dfrac{y}{r} ~\right].$$

So, $~\alpha~$ is defined to be the unique real number such that $~0 \leq \alpha < 2\pi,~$ and such that

$$\cos(\alpha) = \frac{1 - \sin(\theta)}{\sqrt{2 - 2\sin(\theta)}}, ~~\sin(\alpha) = \frac{\cos(\theta)}{\sqrt{2 - 2\sin(\theta)}}. \tag3 $$

---

Thus, with $~r,\alpha~$ defined by (1) and (3) above, you have that the modulus is $~r^n,~$ and the argument is $~n\alpha.$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Write $ie^{i\theta}$ in the form $e^{i\theta'}$ and observe the following picture:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

personally I think the solution that turn the problem to geometry is much easier and more beautiful than algebra

note that $i=e^{i \frac{\pi}{2} }$ so $ie^{i \theta }=e^{i (\frac{\pi}{2}+\theta ) }$ let $\frac{\pi}{2}+\theta =\beta$

then the problem can be turned to the following if $DA=1$ , $AB=\cos(\beta)$  and  $CD=\sin(\beta )$ find $DC$ which in fact equal $|1+e^{i \beta}|$
[image]
it is easy to see that $CD=\sqrt{(1+\cos(\beta))^2+(\sin(\beta ))^2}=\sqrt{2+2\cos(\beta)} =\sqrt{2+2\sin(\theta)}$ so $|1+ie^{i \theta}|^n=(\sqrt{2+2\sin(\theta)})^n$

to find $\arg((1+ie^{i \theta})^n)$ we need to find $\angle BDC =\arctan({\frac{\sin(\beta)}{1+\cos(\beta)}})$ note that $-\pi \leq\beta\leq \pi$ $\frac{\sin(\beta)}{1+\cos(\beta)}=\frac{2\sin(0.5\beta)\cos(0.5\beta)}{2\cos^2(0.5\beta)} =\tan(0.5\beta)$ so $\angle BDC =\arg(1+ie^{i \theta})=\frac{1}{2}\beta $ then $\arg((1+ie^{i \theta})^n) = n\arg(1+ie^{i \theta})=\frac{n}{2}\beta= \frac{n}{2} (\frac{\pi}{2}+\theta )$

Comment: I didn't go through your calculations, but the final formula is not quite correct. It's "true in spirit", but doesn't work if $\pi/2+\theta > \pi$. For example, if $\theta = 3\pi / 2$, you get $1+ie^{i\theta} = 2$, but $\frac 12(\pi/2 + \theta) = \pi$. What you want to do is replace $\pi/2 + \theta$ with $\theta'\in (-\pi,\pi)$ such that $e^{i(\pi/2+\theta)} = e^{i\theta'}$.

Comment: @Ennar you are right, btw in my solution I named $\theta'$ as $\beta$ then at the final step I just replace it back to $\theta $ blindly

Comment: Almost, $\theta'$ should be your $\beta$ if $\beta \leq \pi$ and $\beta - 2\pi$ otherwise.